What the difference between "disengage" and "disconnect"?
The Boeing 777 uses the word "disengage" for autopilot and "disconnect" for autothrottle?
What's the difference between "disengage" and "disconnect"? Why didn't they use the same word for both of them?

Aside from some tech writer's stylistic preference or convention (and there are plenty of those out there), the practical distinction between the two words is basically nil.
There is no difference in meaning between talking about "disconnecting the autopilot" or "disengaging the autopilot", nor using either term with the autothrottles.  You will hear both terms used.
As a matter of preferring one term over the other, I hear more often to "engage" the autopilot, so "disengage" is probably the most consistent term to use when talking about turning it off. But nobody is going to be confused, or have any difference of meaning understood, by using the terms interchangeably.
